# chrome.tabs problems with chrome.tabs.update and chrome.tabs.executeScript

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to write a small chrome extension which shall take an information from webpage A (current webpage), update the tab to webpage B and then inject code into webpage B. unfortunaetelly the following code is updating the webpage to B but injecting the code to webpage A. The code in background.html is:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{url: "http://B.com"});
chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "inject_into_B.com.js"}); /* injections goes misleadingly to webpage A*/
```

Answer (score 7):

You want something like this:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {url: request.url, active: true}, function(tab1) {

    // add listener so callback executes only if page loaded. otherwise calls instantly
    var listener = function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {

        if (tabId == tab1.id && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
            // remove listener, so only run once
            chrome.tabs.onUpdated.removeListener(listener);
            // do stuff
        }
    }
    chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(listener);
});
```

Comment: This worked for me, where serg's answer did not.  Oddly, I had been using the method serg had suggested for a while, which had worked, and just noticed it wasn't working anymore.  In trying to fix it, I found your solution did so.

Comment: @Keven Thank you so much, you helped me a lot !

Comment: @Keven, Can I get tab's html content for given url?

Answer (score 2):

`chrome.tabs.update` is asynchronous call (like pretty much all others), so if you want to run those commands in order you need to use a callback function:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id,{url: "http://B.com"}, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "inject_into_B.com.js"});
});
```

Comment: if i add the code alert("done") at the end of inject_into_B.com.js, i see that (even with your code) the alert is fired at webpage A, thus we can say that the calls are still asynchronous : /